# Problem on speed of light in a refractive medium

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, classical-mechanics, refraction, textbook-erratum

Here's the problem:
A beam of light moves in a slab of refractive index ***n*** in positive ***x*** direction. The slab itself is also moving in the positive ***x*** direction with respect to the lab frame. What is the speed of light as measured in the lab frame?
My guess is ***c/n*** yet the answer given is ***c***. Can anyone please explain where I'm going wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: I'd expect you to need to use [relativistic velocity addition](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Relativ/einvel.html), but that solution is different both from your answer and your reference answer. Could you post the exact text of the problem? The lame trick suggested in your current answer ("the sneaky textbook author meant the speed of light in vacuum, not in the refracting material, sneaky sneaky") is unsatisfying.

Comment: I did post the exact text of the question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer $c$ does not seem to make any sense because it does not look correct for zero velocity of the slab.

However, your answer does not look good either: the light moves with velocity $c/n$ with respect to the slab, to obtain the velocity with respect to the lab, you need to apply the Lorentz transform.

EDIT: (12/6/2016) On the other hand, what they may have in mind is that the front of a light pulse always moves with speed $c$, but that would be strange.

EDIT: (12/7/2016) Looks like I fell for the trick:-( In the problem, they do not ask about the speed of the beam of light in the slab in the lab frame, they ask about speed of light in the lab frame:-), apparently, meaning the speed of light in vacuum, which is indeed $c$, so it looks like they distract and fool a reader by the details of  the slab and the beam of light:-)

Comment: The speed of light is the same in all frames of reference, isn't it?

Comment: @BudhadityaBhattacharjee: The speed of light in a vacuum is the same in all frames of reference (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity). Although see my last edit:-)

Comment: Such a lame tricky question.